# How connect two Python programs?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I have a Python 2.7 program that collects voltages into a logfile, then it uses a `sys.exit()` at the end of this first program to stop and go back to the Linux command prompt line.

At the Linux command prompt line I type in `sudo python plotprogram.py` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start the second Python 2.7 program.

Is there a way to add script at the end of the first program that will exit it and automatically go into the second program?

Comment: `python plotprogram.py && python secondprogram.py`?

Comment: explicitly calling `sys.exit()` is pretty rude.  Do you have control over the program that calls it?  Does it make reasonable sense to change that to something like `return`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in many ways. Write a `Python` file and include these two `Python` files to execute, you can use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) or you can do something like this :

`sudo python file.py ; sudo python file2.py`